# How to get only one element from an array (firebase database, nodejs)

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase

If I use `limitToLast(1)`, then I still get an object, with one key-value pair. To get the value, I use this code:

```
db.ref('/myarray').limitToLast(1).once('value').then(function(snapshot) {

    var result = snapshot.val();
    var lastElem;
    var lastKey;

    for(var i in result) {
        lastElem= result[i];
        lastKey = i;
        break;
    }

    ...

});
```

It works, but I think I do it wrong. But haven't found any better solution in the docs. How should I load only one element?

The database looks like this:
[image: array]

Comment: Can you show us what the relevant portion of your database looks like? It's difficult to guess, and that's kind of important to solving your problem.

Comment: I edited the question

Comment: So you just want to get the value of any single child of `myarray`?

Comment: The key and the value of the last one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using Firebase queries to get children, use the `"child_added"` event:

```
db.ref("/myarray")
  .orderByKey() // order by chlidren's keys
  .limitToLast(1) // only get the last child
  .once("child_added", function(snapshot) {
    var key = snapshot.key;
    var val = snapshot.val();
    ...
  });
```